# Limit number of allowed values for a label whan scraping targets

Tags: prometheus

Using prometheus it's nice to keep the number of values a label holds low, to make querying faster.

So, for a metric I'm collecting from several (hundreds) of targets I'd like to have a list of allowed values, all other would end as "other".

I can ofcourse do this on my targets but I would much prefer to have it done centrally at the scraper.

One example could be to have the user agent of web requests as a label but rewrite all of them as "chrome", "firefox", "safari" and "other".

Another to put a client specified header value, "client_name", as a label but make sure that only "oneApp" and "anotherApp" are allowed values, and put all the other ones in "inofficialApp".

This is an example
To be clear. This is what I would like for all metrics and from all targets

```
http_request_duration_seconds_count{client_name="the app"} 1
http_request_duration_seconds_count{client_name="the new app"} 1
http_request_duration_seconds_count{client_name="bogus guy 1"} 1
http_request_duration_seconds_count{client_name="bogus guy 2"} 1
```

turns into

```
http_request_duration_seconds_count{client_name="the app"} 1
http_request_duration_seconds_count{client_name="the new app"} 1
http_request_duration_seconds_count{client_name="OTHER"} 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve that with `prometheus` that I know is to use [recording rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/):

```
groups:
  - name: my group
    interval: 30s
    rules:
      - record: my_metric_name:new  # name of new metric
        expr: my_metric_name{instance="foo:9100"}
        labels:
          instance: foo
```

This is far from ideal because you might have to write **a lot** of rules like this. Using it don't forget to use some aggregation in `expr` so that your new metric will have a combined value. Like `sum(my_metric{label1=~"some_regex"}) without (label1)`.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen recording rules but it's really not better than trying to make sure the applications/targets outputs sane values.

Also, it's a bit weird that it doesn't exists since keeping the cardinality low is very important.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand I've added a `relabel_config` example for user-agent. You can use the same approach for apps, you just need to change regular expressions.

Comment: It's clever but what happens if two different user-agents with a count of 1 ends up with the same label value after re-labling? One will be masked? Right?

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand An interesting question! So interesting that I have created an  environment and tested it both with gauge and counter metric types. It turned out that messing with label values using relabeling will leave you with one value. The last one that was processed. Thus I think my initial answer was correct as it is the only way to apply aggregation over processed metrics and have correct value in the end.

Comment: yes, and that means thousands, or tens of thousands, of recording rules, exaclty what I want to avoid. I really hoped there would another answer but perhaps not.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand not thousands, tens. For example to grab all user agents with 'Chrome' you can do `my_metric{user_agent=~".*Chrome.*"}`. To save all other labels as they are use `sum(my_metric{user_agent=~".*Chrome.*"})without(user_agent)`. Then you have to have one like this per each user-agent you want to see. That's not much I think.

Comment: for each metric I need a recording rule that replaces my metric. Remeber, I want this label to change for ALL my metrics, and there are thousands of metrics.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand I've been this over again and I have another idea. Using relabel_config you can add a new label isntead of replacing value in an existing one. This way you will not lose data because metrics will remain distinct and you will have a label with a short list of possible values to query by.

Comment: Thank you for the hard work, but my main consern is the number of data series this will result in. That's why I want to make sure the number of values on the label is limited to a certain list of allowed values. 

I think my only option is to implent this list on each target instead.

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty but not accepting the answer.